# counting number of pairs with same elem value in python list

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand why the function is returning 4 while it should return 3. Thank you very much.

```
x = [10,20,20,10,10,30,50,10,20]
s = {} 
count = 0 
for item in x: 
  if (item in s): 
   s[item] += 1
 else:
   s[item] = 1
for z, w in s.items(): 
 count += w/2 
print(int(count))
```

Comment: I tried so many ways to solve this homework. I pushed my self beyond my limits 10 times. I started getting frustrated. Would you please instruct me how to solve the problem coz I am very tired and starting losing control. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of what you said, of wanting to count pairs, then I believe you would want to round down the number being added to count instead of count overall, as 2 halves would end up making 1.

The following does return 3.

```
x = [10,20,20,10,10,30,50,10,20]
s = {} 
count = 0 
for item in x: 
  if (item in s): 
   s[item] += 1
 else:
   s[item] = 1
for z, w in s.items(): 
 count += int(w/2) 
print(count)
```

Comment: thank you veeeeeery much duckboycool, maybe it is nothing for you but it is very big favor for me. my Full Respect.

Comment: A slightly better solution would be to use `count += w//2` which does integer division, instead of doing float division and then converting it back to integer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a single slash ”/“ does a regular divide that returns with decimals. A double slash “//“ returns a whole number rounded down. When you call int() on the number, it rounds it down to nearest whole number.

In your code, you get:
2+1.5+0.5+0.5=4.5

After calling int on 4.5, it becomes 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding floats in the for loop, just change that to ints and it will add up to 3.

```
x = [10,20,20,10,10,30,50,10,20]
s = {}
count = 0
for item in x:
    if (item in s):
        s[item] += 1
    else:
        s[item] = 1
for z, w in s.items():
    count += int(w/2)

print(int(count))
```